# How do I go about implementing different behaviors on items?

Tags: c#, architecture

How do I go about implementing different items with different behaviors?

I plan on having an inventory where those items are stored, but I can't figure out how do I go about implementing different functionality for each item.
Can somebody help me figure out where to look or how to go about this problem?

(This is not a question about inventory implementation, or specific item implementation, but how to implement functionalities of each usable item.)

Comment: this seems a little broad but i think you should create a single method that will handle base features, then use this across different items. If an item has a different set of features, create it a new class with a set of methods.

Comment: Each item is pretty much a different feature, most items don't do what others do. The only thing they have in common that they're in one inventory. I'm just asking if there's a nice way of making this without hundreds of classes for each item type.

Comment: Not really, i mean from a programmers point of view you probably could have one class called ItemFunctions, then methods for each different type of item, and just call a specific method based on an items ID. Thats how i would do it.

Comment: Any chance of an example of the concept? It sounds like a good idea(write it as an answer).

Comment: I think someone has wrote an answer basically using what i suggested, id check that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for some simple OOP.

Start with a class for each item. Something simple will do. This class' job is to define the basic interface that is used to interact with items.

```
class IItem
{
    String Name;
    Sprite Icon;

    virtual void Use() = 0;
}
```

Now, each item that  you want a new behaviour for, should implement this interface, and place the interaction code in the `Use` method. When your player or other object wants to use the item, you simply call the `Use` method from the item wanted, and perhaps destroy the item. You could also allow the item to determine when it wants to be destroyed by adding a `ShouldBeDeleted()` method. Items that have multiple uses would use a counter and determine the deletion state by investigating that counter.

```
class Apple : IItem
{
    Apple() 
    {
        Name = "Apple";
        Icon = SpriteManager.Load("Apple.png");
    }

    override void Use(Player player) 
    {
        player.hunger -= 5;
    }
}
```

This kind of pattern should work just fine, as long as you don't have very many items. For a basic game this should however work just fine. You also might want to look into the factory pattern, where instead of `Inventory.Add(new Apple());`, you would instead as a factory object to create the item for you, along the lines of `Inventory.Add(ItemFactor.Create(ItemType.Apple));`.

Comment: Follow up question; what would the Inventory type be then?

Comment: A simple `List<IItem>` should do just fine.